# Windows.Storage namespace not visible in portable class library project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a portable class library targeting .NET 4.5, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1

I'm unable to use the `StorageFolder` class which resides in the `Windows.Storage` namespace (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.aspx).

The only reference in the project's References branch is named `.NET` and object browsing it  shows it does have `StorageFolder` class located under `Windows`, under `Windows.Storage` namespace.
But when I try to add a reference, I just see a small list of available assemblies which does not have anything with Windows in it.

I'm using VS2013 with update 3 on a Windows 8.1 x64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're using the object browser incorrectly.  By default it will show **All Components**

[image]

To get to what you actually have, you need to select "***.NET Portable Subset (Visual Studio 2013)***"

If you really want to add the Windows.Storage then you have to select

"All Components" and search for **Windows.winmd**

Highlight that Component then click on the "Add to References in Selected Project in Solution Explorer" Button.  Located here:

[image]

That will add that reference over to the Portable Library project (which imho, defeats the purpose)

Then in your Class1.cs you can you use your StorageFolder

---

[image]

Comment: This was an awesome explanation with screenshots. Thank you so much! Also I could not understand why adding that reference defeats the purpose? Do you mean that this assembly is not meant to be included in portable class libraries?

Comment: I'm not sure if your portable library will work since you also targeted 4.5 in your requirements.  Unless you do some weird complier and switch file operations to something like System.IO for Desktop apps that uses 4.5.  I could be wrong, I'm not entirely sure.  I guess, load it up into a WinForm app and try :), good luck.

Comment: i can't find it